# would in "The barrel would hold 20 gallons"

Tags: meaning

My question is about sense 9 of the word 'would' in M-W.

https://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would

9: could *'The barrel would hold 20 gallons.'*

Does 'could' here indicate ability or possibility? Also is this sentence in the past tense or present?

Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ambiguous. ;)  It could refer to either ability or possibility.  That is, it could refer to the *construction* of the barrel: "The barrel won't break if you fill it with 20 gallons of [whatever]."  But more commonly, it refers to *capacity* without reference to construction: "The interior volume of the barrel is 20 gallons. Its ability to withstand the force of various contents is left unspecified."

Since this sentence is "declarative" rather than "episodic", it doesn't really have a tense.  What I mean is that it describes a property of an object that is presumed to be stable over time, rather than a property that is transient and only expected to hold for some moment of relevance.  It's like asking: "What is the tense of the statement: 'A square has four sides'?"  Grammatically speaking, it's present tense.  But it would be odd to say: "A square had four sides" or "A square will have four sides" (the latter occurs in some dialects, but is surely less common than the "present" tense).

In some uses, "would" refers to a hypothetical future tense: "If we pour all the oil into the barrel, what outcome do you expect?"  "The barrel would hold 20 gallons."

Comment: Thank you very much Lawnmower Man. :-) Now I understand. I asked M-W this question and someone responded "I don't know how to answer this one.".